# No matching distribution found for cv-bridge python

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I have a script in python that uses cv-bridge. But I keep getting this error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv-bridge==1.15.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv-bridge==1.15.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))

To reproduce the error:
pip install -r requirements.txt

requirements.txt:
cv-bridge==1.15.0

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: "cv bridge" is something related to ROS. look for that. your code may be very old and nothing support it anymore. I see that it claims to deal with `IplImage`... and that is at least 5-10 years out of date. OpenCV uses its own format, not `IplImage`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually install CV_Bridge and your script is failing because it cannot find a match for the exact version. As mentioned in the comment, this is almost certainly because of how old that version is. You should install the bridge via `apt` by doing `sudo apt-get install ros-(DISTRO)-cv-bridge` and `sudo apt-get install ros-(DISTRO)-vision-opencv`.